# Testing for structural breaks by adding time dummies

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, structural-change

I'm preparing for exams and one sample question asks about an analysis of the following reported linear regression model:

$$
Y_t = \underset{(3.21)}{105.68} + \underset{(.121)}{.074}X_t - \underset{(.156)}{.006} X_{t-1} + \underset{(.115)}{.034}X_{t-2} - \underset{(2.37)}{4.22}WW1_t - \underset{(7.29)}{18.01}WW2_t - \underset{(4.01)}{31.42}CW_t
\\
\overline{R}^2 = .45
$$

where data is from 1900 to the end of the Cold War. The WW1, WW2, and CW dummies all are time dummies for the world wars and Cold War (the Cold War dummy lasts to the end of the dataset).

The problem states that the reason why the time dummies were added was because the researcher feared a structural break, and asks how to test for a structural break during WW1, and to report the test statistic. (and to do this for WW2, and the Cold War).

I am confused here because I thought that to test for a structural break you need to compute a Chow statistic, but no SSR is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to compute the Chow statistic for this (and similar) cases, and, as you note, in any case you can't.  You'd need the results of several different regressions in order to do so.  But the Chow test is not the only way to test for a structural break; depending on how the break is modeled, other off-the-shelf tests are applicable.

What is a "structural break" as modeled in the regression above?  In the case of $WW1$, it's modeled as a change in the intercept.  If the estimated change in the $WW1$ intercept, in this case $-4.22$, is insignificant, that's sufficient to conclude that the data does not support the hypothesis that there is a structural break corresponding to $WW1$.

$WW2$ and $CW$ are modeled in the same way, and using the same thought process leads to the same conclusion - that testing for the significance of the estimated coefficient on the relevant dummy variable is equivalent to testing for the structural break *as modeled*.